# Are SparkListener/StreamingListener callbacks called concurrently?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

What is the concurrency model behind [`SparkListener`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener) or [`StreamingListener`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.StreamingListener) callbacks?

1. Multiple threads might access callbacks simultaneously.
2. Callbacks are guaranteed to be executed by a single thread.(Thread ids might change on consecutive calls, though)